# Create text Files for every row in an Excel spreadsheet with data from different text files

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a script that creates new text files with content from other text files considering values from a column.
I have column A filled with 10 names, column B filled with numbers that range from 1 to 3, and a folder with 10 text files that have numbers as names (from 1 to 10).
I need to create a text file for each name in the A column that considers the value in B column with text from the text files.
The text files content contains 3 different lines:

1content1

2content2

3content3

For the first name if the value in column b same row is 1 the newly created text file would need to contain only the first row of the first text file (1): "1content1" and so on.

Is this possible? How would I go about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your data is as in the image below.

[image]

Here,

1. Column `A` contains the file name to be created
2. Column `B` has the line number ranging from 1 to 3

Few things for consideration:

- As you said mentioned that you already have 10 text files in a folder having names 1 to 10, I am picking those files for each row in data. For example row 1 will create a new file by name `File_A` where data will be Line no. 1 of file with name `1.txt`in your specified folder. Then for row 2 new file by name `File_B` will be created where data will be Line no. 2 of file with name `2.txt` and so on.(I guess this is clear)
- Code will save newly created file in the same folder where you 10 files are already saved.

```
Sub CreateTextFile()
    Dim hf As Integer: hf = FreeFile
    Dim lines() As String
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, FileLine As Long, LineNum As Long, lineCntr As Long
    Dim FileName As String, FilePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object, oFile As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")    '---->change Sheet1 to your worksheet name
    FilePath = "C:\test_folder\"        '---->change filepath as required
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        FileName = FilePath & i & ".txt"
        LineNum = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value      

        'reading text file line by line
        Open FileName For Input As #hf
            lines = Split(Input$(LOF(hf), #hf), vbNewLine)
        Close #hf

        'writing particular line to new text file
        For lineCntr = 0 To UBound(lines)
            If lineCntr + 1 = LineNum Then
                Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(FilePath & ws.Cells(i, 1) & ".txt")
                oFile.WriteLine lines(lineCntr)
                oFile.Close
            End If
        Next lineCntr
    Next i
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: @splertok - Glad I could help you. If this solution answers you question kindly mark it as an answer.